# Why does the mirror modifier create a new object instead of mirroring the object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

When I mirror my object it seems to create a new object instead of just mirroring.
I've changed cursor to selected object but it's still not helping.
Please someone help me[image: mirrored object (the plane) standing side by side instead of being just one object.].

Comment: You have moved the object away from it's origin point. In edit mode, move the plane towards its "mirror". You should be able to see what's happening. Often, when mirroring something, you cut it in half first, down the middle, so the edge of the "half" that's left over lines up with the origin.

Comment: Off topic; imho you should be using some form of "Screen Capture" instead of taking a picture of your screen. It would be so much more efficient in a lot of ways.

Comment: @Dontwalk lol I didn't even think about that, the problem had me confused. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this is not a separate object , its just a physically separate mesh, which means that these 2 planes are the part of the same object , this is happening because you object origin is not at the correct place thats why you re getting weird results , you can right click on the object to set origin or in edit mode change the position of the object

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that the mesh isn't lining up with the origin, and mirror modifier works by using the object's origin as the mirroring point by default.

To fix it you can go to Edit Mode, select all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then move the geometry towards the origin with <kbd>G</kbd>.

You seem to have "Clipping" enabled, so when you move them together, the sides will automatically merge and it'll have the look of a single object again.